# iOS scan for radio channels

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm looking to scan for radio staion using an iOS device. I have no idea how to even begin this. I'm well versed in Objective-c; this is just not something I'm familiar with.

A point in the right direction would be fantastic.

Comment: AM, FM, VHF, Short-Wave?  What do you think you mean by "radio station"?

Comment: Maybe he means internet radio stations ? Who knows...

Comment: I'm still getting those details to be honest :p Let's say it was AM Radio. I see that Malcolm says no but just search TuneIn Radio in the app store. These do exist. Except what I'm looking to build would serve a more specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official support in Apple SDKs for accessing the FM radio hardware, so even if you managed to find out how to access the hardware and got it working, you'd be unable to distribute the app.

There is apparently FM radio hardware from Broadcom in the iPod touch 3rd gen, but whether it is accessible is an open question.